# How to print all environment variables in TCL?

Tags: environment-variables, tcl

In TCL, how can I print all environment variables using a single line command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an array called env that stores all the environment variables. So you can simply do this:

```
puts [array get env]
```

or simply

```
parray env
```

Comment: The difference between the two is that `parray` sorts the keys, does nice indentation, and otherwise generally makes the output easy to read. `array get` doesn't; it's intended mainly for serialization of an array's data (ready to use with `array set`).

Comment: puts [array get env] - for me this prints nothing at all ?